# Equivalent of eval() in Groovy

Tags: groovy

In python, I can use eval() to execute user entered code in my program.
Is there anything similar I can do in Groovy? I want to have a SWING UI textbox where the user enters a piece of code that I want to execute?

Thanks,
Hari

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are multiple ways of running Groovy (from both inside Java and Groovy):

http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html

The quickest method however (for simple scripts), is probably to use the Eval class:

http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html#integ-eval

Which would let you do something like:

```
Eval.me( '2 + 2' )
```

See this page from more examples:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-simple-evaluation-of.html

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to dynamically evaluate code in Groovy by using Eval.x, Eval.xy, Eval.xyz or Eval.me. See [the API doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) for more details about these methods.

For example, you use Eval.me like this:

```
def a = "hello"
def b = "world" 
Eval.me(""" println "$a $b" """)
--> hello world
```

Also, see [this blog post for some eval examples](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-simple-evaluation-of.html)

Comment: You mean `Eval.xy( a, b, 'println "$x $y"' )` surely? ;-)

Comment: Nice catch, thanks. Changed from Eval.x to Eval.me. On the use of Eval.xy vs Eval.x - it's a matter of preference. In this case you can use either of them. Also, you can either use ' or """.

Comment: As it is, this solution evaluates `$a` and `$b` in the string passed to `Eval.me` - they are not evaluated by `Eva.lme`... I don't think that was the intention?

Answer (score 4):

Try this (but as usual with eval in any scripting language be careful about malicious code exeution):

```
evaluate("print new Date()")
```

Comment: I am trying to run a small piece of code in my custom grammar - will definitely check for malicious code.