# Closure from String

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

How to create a closure from a string?

Like I have a string `def formula = "{it * it}"`

Now formula is a string and I can't do formula()

how do I define the code block in the string variable formula as a closure?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
def formula = Eval.me( "{ x -> x * x}" )

formula( 3 )
```

Obviously the usual warnings about the safety of evaluating strings entered by users apply

[You might also be interested in a nearly identical question that was asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265748/need-groovy-syntax-help-for-generating-a-closure-from-a-string)