# Build dynamic closure list from a list in order to pass it to OrderBy in Groovy

Tags: list, groovy, closures

I am following [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/12/groovy-goodness-using-orderby.html) article to set the Order for sorting.

Excerpt from above article

```
class Language {
    String name
    boolean dynamic
    String toString() { "name: $name, dynamic: $dynamic" }
}
 
def languages = [
    new Language(name: 'Groovy', dynamic: true),
    new Language(name: 'Java', dynamic: false),
    new Language(name: 'Clojure', dynamic: true)
]
def list = ['name', 'dynamic']
sh = new GroovyShell()
closure = sh.evaluate("{  }")
def cList = list.collect { closure(it) }
println cList
 
// We order first on dynamic property and then name property.
def orderByDynamicAndName = new OrderBy([{ it.dynamic }, { it.name }])
```

Here, I would like to pass the list of closures dynamically from a list.

Say, there is a list and **list may vary** in element size in different applications / classes. *This is main reason I wanted the dynamic closure list.*

```
def list = ['name', 'dynamic']
```

From the above list, want to generate it as list of closure and pass it to `OrderBy` class as argument.

```
//Build closure list. But, not sure how to generate it from above list
def cList = 

def orderByDynamicAndName = new OrderBy(cList)
```

Tried to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129067/load-closure-code-from-string-in-groovy) thread, but some how could not generate `cList` as desired

Tried to build `cList` as shown below; getting errors

```
def list = ['name', 'dynamic']
sh = new GroovyShell()
closure = sh.evaluate("{ fieldName -> \"it\".fieldName }")
def cList = list.collect { closure(it) }
```

Error:

> Exception thrown
>
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: fieldName for class: java.lang.String

How to over come this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Language {
    String name
    boolean dynamic
    String toString() { "name: $name, dynamic: $dynamic" }
}

def languages = [
    new Language(name: 'Groovy', dynamic: true),
    new Language(name: 'Java', dynamic: false),
    new Language(name: 'Clojure', dynamic: true)
]

def list = ['dynamic', 'name']
def cList = list.collect{ propName-> { target-> target[propName] } }

def orderBy = new OrderBy(cList)
def sortedLanguages = languages.toSorted(orderBy)

println languages
println sortedLanguages
```

actually this expression

```
list.collect{ propName-> { target-> target[propName] } }
```

converts list of property names to list of closures

```
['dynamic', 'name'] => [ { target-> target['dynamic'] }, { target-> target['name'] } ]
```

and `target` is just a parameter name in the closure.

later, when we call `sort`, each closure `{ target-> target[propName] }` will be called against an object in a sorting array and our closure returns the value by a property name.

Comment: Thank for the solution, will check it.

Comment: Would you please explain the statement that is fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, below code worked for me in order to create the list of closures.

```
def list = ['dynamic', 'name']
def tempClosureString = list.collect { element -> "{it.$element}" }.join(',')
def cList = new GroovyShell().evaluate("[ $tempClosureString ]")

def orderByDynamicAndName = new OrderBy(cList)
```

I welcome if there are better alternatives.