# How to script input for a Java program

Tags: java, groovy, dsl

I'm writing a Java program that requires its (technical) users to write scripts that it uses as input; it interprets these scripts into a series of actions and executes them. I am currently looking for the cleanest way to implement the script/configuration language. I was originally thinking of heading down the XML route, but the nature of the required input really is a procedural, linear *flow* of actions that need to be executed:

```
function move(Block b, Position p) {
    // user-defined algorithm for moving block "b" to position "p"
}

Block a = getBlockA();
Position p = getPositionP();

move(a, p);
```

Etc. **Please note**: the above is an *example* only and **does not** constitute the exact syntax I am looking to achieve. I am still in the "30,000 ft view"-design phase, and don't know what my concreted scripting language will ultimately look like. I only provide this example to show that it is a flow/procedural *script* that the users must write, and that XML is probably not the *best* candidate for its implementation.

XML, perfect for hierarchial data, just doesn't feel like the best choice for such an implementation (although I could *force* it to work if need-be).

Not knowing a lick about DSLs, I've begun to read up on Groovy DSLs and they feel like a perfect match for what I need.

My *uderstanding* is that I could write, say, a Groovy (I'm stronger in Groovy than Scala, JRuby, etc.) DSL that would allow users to write scripts (`.groovy` files) that my program could then execute as input at runtime.

Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding the intent of DSLs altogether? If I am mistaken, does anybody have any suggestions for me? And if I am correct then how would a Java program read and execute a `.groovy` file (in other words, how would my program "consume" their script)?

**Edit**: I'm beginning to like ANTLR. Although I would love to roll up my sleeves and write a Groovy DSL, I don't want my users to be able to write any old Groovy program they want. I want my own "micro-language" and if users step outside of it I want the interpreter to invalidate the script. It's beginning to seem like Groovy/DSLs aren't the right choice, and maybe ANTLR could be the solution I need...?

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/).

Comment: @Bart: how current is BeanShell? The page you referenced has a "BeanShell in the News" link that references a 2000 Java Developer's Journal article.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, it's rather old-school, and (AFAIK) not actively being developed on. But it may serve Zac's purpose: the example code he posted can pretty much be copy-pasted and used as a Beanshell script and used in a Java application.

Comment: Have a look at [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/), it is very pleasant to write DSLs with it (and it is actively developed!)

Comment: @Zac You seem to be (faintly) mistaken about the purpose of DSLs. They're mostly used to implement a declarative-ish specialised language (e.g. for configuration) on top of a mainly procedural language. That's not to say you're on the wrong path. If your users are going to write mostly procedural code and you just need to have a sane way to load / evaluate it at runtime, you can use straight Groovy and a binding to your Java code.

Comment: Thanks @millimoose - but if I went that route would my input scripts be regular Groovy or would I get to restrict the types of things my users could script (which is what I want).

Comment: @ZacHarvey They'd be regular Groovy. However, so would a Groovy-based DSL. If you want restricted execution, you need a language / environment designed for it. Lua is generally a great choice for that, but I don't know how easy it is to integrate with Java. (Another option might be using the Java code security stuff, but I have no idea how that works or if it can implement the kind of restrictions you need.)

Comment: Thanks again @millimoose (+1) - please see my edit and my thinking regarding ANTLR. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I guess at the root of my question regarding DSLs is this: are DSLs nothing more than APIs or are they actually they're own languages? Meaning, if I wrote a "Block Moving" DSL for Groovy, would it truly be its own, restrictive language (**restrictive** in that you could *only* call the methods I define such as `move(Block, Position)`, etc.), or would it just define a bunch of functions that my user's could use, but still allow for traditional Groovy coding?

Comment: DSLs, at least in the Rubyland/Groovyland meaning of the term, are APIs. Both of those languages are "DSL-friendly", which mean it's possible to create an API that doesn't really look like it is one. (E.g.  you can omit most brackets, and write constructs similar to natural language like in RSpec. Or they let you write constructs that map to the problem domain better, like with Groovy's SwingBuilder.) But the general idea is to make an API surface more convenient, not more restricive.

Comment: I can't remember where I read a certain article about this; I'll have to make do without a citation: creating a programming language is *hard*. ANTLR is just the first of several steps involved. Personally I'd first look into all the existing options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write a Groovy program that will accept a script as input and execute it. I recently wrote a BASIC DSL/interpreter in this way using groovy :

http://cartesianproduct.wordpress.com/binsic-is-not-sinclair-instruction-code/

(In the end it was more interpreter than DSL but that was to do with a peculiarity of Groovy that likely won't affect you - BASIC insists on UPPER CASE keywords which Groovy finds hard to parse - hence they have to be converted to lower case).

Groovy allows you to extend the script environment in various ways (eg injecting variables into the binding and transferring execution from the current script to a different, dynamically loaded script) which make this relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on a really good path. Your users can write their files using your simple DSL and them you can run them by Evaling them at runtime. Your biggest challenge will be helping them to use the API of your DSL correctly. Unless they use an IDE this will be pretty tough.

[Equivalent of eval() in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264014/equivalent-of-eval-in-groovy)