# Groovy script in Jenkins: Evaluate a string

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need to reproduce the following Python code in [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software)) [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Groovy)

```
city='Petersburg'
varname='city'
varvalue=eval(varname)
print(varvalue) # prints 'Petersburg'
```

that is I need to assign the value of a variable to another variable knowing the name of the source variable as a string. Please provide the same code written in Jenkins Groovy (which I can insert into a `Jenkinsfile`). Supplemental detail: Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264014/equivalent-of-eval-in-groovy) I tried groovy [eval](http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html#integ-eval) class

```
city='Petersburg'
varname='city'
varvalue=Eval.me(varname)
println(varvalue)
```

it output the following error in Jenkins console output

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting ''', found '<EOF>' @ line 1, column 15.
       varvalue='city
```

I also tried the following code (using Groovy Eval as Python exec)

```
city='Petersburg'
varname='city'
Eval.me('varvalue=\'' + varname)
println(varvalue)
```

whitch produced the same error

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
    Script1.groovy: 1: expecting ''', found '<EOF>' @ line 1, column 15.
       varvalue='city
```

Comment: Try `varvalue=evaluate varname` or `varvalue=evaluate(varname)`

Comment: @NoamHelmer
Dear Noam
both of your solutions work! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.
thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Eval.me` function evaluates the script in a separated execution context and therefore cannot access the variables you defined before accessing it (See [Eval Documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html)).
So to use it you will have to pass the binding of the parameters so it will recognize it, something like:

```groovy
city='Petersburg'
varname='city' 
varvalue=Eval.me('city', 'Petersburg', varname)
println(varvalue)​
```

But passing the parameter bindings probably contradicts what you are trying to achieve, so instead you can use the [evaluate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Script.html#evaluate(java.lang.String)) function which allows the dynamic evaluation of groovy expressions using this scripts binding as the variable scope. Something like:

```groovy
city='Petersburg'
varname='city' 
varvalue=evaluate(varname)
println(varvalue)​
```

You can also use `varvalue=evaluate varname` as groovy allows to omit the parentheses when running the function with a single parameter.